# Issue with background image (won't show)

Tags: html, css, image

I got issue with background image on my webpage (won't show). I tried to place it in different `<div>`s but I cannot find solution, how to solve it. Also I tried to find solution here, but nothing worked for me. I don't have written long path to image, because all is in one folder. Also I know, I have it little chaotic.
I don't want to repair my wrongs, but just want to know how I can solve it and why it not work.

[Here is my HTML source](http://pastebin.com/pRhdbaP8)

[And here is my CSS source](http://pastebin.com/fEFiE2tj)

Comment: "_I don't want to repair my wrongs, but just want to know how I can solve it and why it not work._" This sentences confuses me.

Comment: It's difficult to determine the cause at the moment. The relevant part of your code should be included in the body of your question. In addition, you should try and reproduce the issue in one of the many online sandboxes like http://jsfiddle.net and http://codepen.io

Comment: @Boaz Thanks, I will have this in my head for next time. I tried to use w3s validator, but it didn't helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the URL within quotes, within the CSS file in the background property of the CSS file. `url(limo.jpg)` should instead be `url("limo.jpg")`

Answer (score 0):

Depends what browser you're on. Try putting limo.jpg in quotation marks and adjusting to background-image:

```
body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        background-image: url("limo.jpg") no-repeat center fixed; 
        background-size: cover;
            }
```